# Android Instrumentation Tests Stuck "Running Tests" Forever Android Studio

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso, android-studio-2.0, gradle-android-test-plugi

I use Android Espresso Tests with latest Android Studio 2.1.2 and Tests are running ok but it does not seems like the standalone test app returns back the results to reflect back to Android Studio and it shows Running Tests Forever

Answer (score 8):

I realize this is an old question, but I just ran into this and didn't see any other search results that had the same problem.

In my case, this was caused by the code under test having a stack overflow exception, which it seems that the test runner failed to handle.  I was only able to figure it out by looking at the "Android Monitor" and looking in the logcat.

So if you get to the point where AS just sits at "running test" forever, you might want to look in logcat for an exception that the test runner couldn't handle.

Comment: very helpful answer thanks

Comment: In my case one test in a queue threw an error (view id was not found). Later one of the tests didn't finish forever.

Answer (score 1):

You have to try removing testCoverageEnabled option from build.gradle file if it's there.
possible duplicate
[Gradle build tool long for android Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849945/gradle-build-too-long/39865956#39865956)

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone.
In my case, I was setting the idle state wrongly(false instead of true) after doing a background task, so espresso was stuck thinking that was idle.