# Gradle Build too long

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-build

Gradle build now takes too long (literally it does not complete building after running for like 1 hour) after enabling MultiDex. I followed the steps given at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html site to configure MultiDex in app.

Below is an excerpt from my gradle console.

```
:app:compileDevelopmentDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDevelopmentDebugSources
:app:mergeDevelopmentDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDevelopmentDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDevelopmentDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDevelopmentDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:unzipJacocoAgent UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithJacocoForDevelopmentDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDevelopmentDebug
```

the last task `:app:transformClassesWithDexForDevelopmentDebug` is the one where the gradle console stops. Any help would be appreciated. I also need to test the app in pre-lollipop devices.

**Edit**

The problem only occurs when I test my app in a pre-lollipop test device. Building for main test device seems to work fine. It takes 8.12 seconds while building for Nexus 6P. But I want to test for pre-lollipop devices too.

**Edit 2**

As per @Gillis's advice I am attaching my stacktrace

```
10:19:10.558 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
10:19:10.558 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
10:19:10.559 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
10:19:10.559 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
10:19:10.559 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
10:19:10.559 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
10:19:10.559 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
10:19:20.555 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
10:19:20.560 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
10:19:20.560 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
10:19:20.561 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
10:19:20.561 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
10:19:20.561 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
10:19:20.561 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
```

I have tried removing my `/home/.gradle` folder too but still no luck. Clearly there is a loop in acquiring the lock.

Also I am attaching my jstacktrace too

```
"File lock request listener" #27 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fb9b2c20800 nid=0x5d07 runnable [0x0000700001961000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)
        - locked <0x00000006c026d670> (a java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:143)
        - locked <0x00000006c026d670> (a java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:812)
        - locked <0x00000006c0bc5df0> (a java.net.DatagramPacket)
        - locked <0x00000006c026d630> (a java.net.DatagramSocket)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileLockCommunicator.receive(FileLockCommunicator.java:60)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler$1.doRun(DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.java:67)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler$1.run(DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

please refer [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/u9k4bfCi) for complete log.

Comment: for question like *Compilation takes too long* the answer is simple ... buy better PC/Mac

Comment: iMac (27-inch, Late 2012) 3.2 GHz Intel Core i5, 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 , NVIDIA GeForce GTX 675MX 1024 MB

Comment: As @Selvin says if your pc configuration is low then its normal to take time but i assume its not that low that it would take hour to complete build even in my dual core it complete within 1 or 2 min.

Comment: @androidXP I clearly stated I tried using MultiDex as I had dex overflow error earlier with number of methods exceeding 65k. I used a significant amount of libraries.

Comment: believe it or not the problem is cuz of your internet connection check offline work in settings->Buildtools->Gradle and try again.

Comment: I've tried that too. Its a multi-dex assembly issue. Pre-Lollipop does not have ART compiler and Assembly is done in a bit different way. But still the time taken is way too high.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your much appreciated help. I solved this issue. Apparently the issue was because (I suppose that) the JaCoCo was dexing along with my class dexing and was issuing a locks. I fixed this by removing the `testCoverageEnabled=true` line in my app's build.gradle.

In case any of you guys run into similar issue. Create two build flavours (prod and development) and add the line `testCoverageEnable=true` only for development flavor and set it to false else where. Also ensure that your development has the `minSdkVersion` set to 21 (Lollipop) as the dexing is done for ART and basically you won't be running into this issue.

Comment: But if you remove "testCoverageEnable", you cannot get test coverage report, right?

Comment: create multiple flavour and enable testCoverage for post lollipop versions.

Comment: this solution saved my day

Comment: Thnaks a lot, I was struggling for couple of days to solve this. Though sometimes reason may be different, I would suggest to check this option first if this line is there in gradle file.

Comment: Though build issue went away, but not able to get coverage report. minSdkVersion 21 not working. Also product flavors is not recognizing the word "testCoverageEnabled".

Answer (score 1):

Apart from all the gradle tweaks given in other answers, you can also do something like end the gradle process time to time. In my experience doing that and starting a fresh build solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

go to your app folder in your console and run:

./gradlew build --debug

this gives you a lot of information what goes wrong. 
usually when gradle hangs it is caused by an external dependency which cannot be retreived.

You could try enabling offline mode in android studio to see if this is really the issue.

Comment: Hey man thanks for your advice. I have attached my debug log and stacktrace too. It seems there is a loop in acquiring the wake lock.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
        ....
    }
```

Comment: Tried it and no luck.

Comment: `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m` this is my gradle properties

Comment: If these are not works for your, try clean install android studio.

Answer (score 0):

First Make sure your gradle is Up-To-Date also android studio After update delete invalid cache and restart then at last in **Global Gradle Setting** check "Offline Work" its work for me too give it a try.
[image]

Comment: I've tried that too. I am using gradle version 3.1 and buildTools version 2.2 I've tried with offline work enabled too

Comment: I have an average if not fast internet. So regularly my build's won't take more than 12 seconds. (by build I meant with syncing). My internet speed is 200Mbps which I think is enough for downloading all dependencies in a flash. But to be on safe side I have also tried with offline mode on.

Answer (score 0):

A few tips to increase the Gradle task execution performance:

Gradle Daemon
You can decrease Gradle’s startup time (on my computer down to two seconds) if you tell Gradle to use a daemon to build:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

Parallel Project Execution
This can really make a significant difference if you are building a very complex project with many sub-module dependencies:

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Global gradle.properties

The properties defined in the property file in our home directory take precedence over the properties defined in the file in our project directory. The reasoning behind this is that you want to avoid using the Gradle daemon on your build servers, where startup time is less important than memory consumption:

```
/Users/~/.gradle/gradle.properties
```

[like this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cesarferreira/8f87b2916218e32ae54b/raw/07c6ded23ac1507651ea07927960c7f2182c5ecc/gradle.properties)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `exit(0);` command at the end of your program and it should quit out of this loop