# jammed at "app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug" when open testCoverageEnabled

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

When I build APK without "testCoverageEnabled = true" in app.gradle, it's ok.

Then I try it again with  "testCoverageEnabled = true" , the Gradle Build Running seems jammed at 'app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. I have waited for more than 2 hours, it is still running, but not throw any error message.

My app.build as follows :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'android-aspectjx'
    apply plugin:'jacoco'
    apply plugin: 'com.antfortune.freeline'
    idea{
        module {
            downloadJavadoc = false
            downloadSources = true
        }
    }
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.xx.xx"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 1
            versionName "9.9.99"
            multiDexEnabled true;


            //testInstrumentationRunner 'com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner'
            //testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
            testInstrumentationRunner 'com.xx.xx.runner.CustomTestRunner'
        }

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }


        android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            task "fix${variant.name.capitalize()}TestMultiDexList" << {
                logger.info "Fixing keep manifest for $variant.name"
                def keepManifest = new File("$buildDir/intermediates/multi-dex/test/$variant.flavorName/$variant.buildType.name/manifest_keep.txt")
                keepManifest.append '\n-keep class *.** { *; }\n'
                logger.debug "Updated keepManifest for ${keepManifest.getAbsolutePath()}\n$keepManifest.text"
            }
        }

        tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

                if (task.name == "collect${variant.name.capitalize()}TestMultiDexComponents") {
                    task.finalizedBy "fix${variant.name.capitalize()}TestMultiDexList"
                }
            }

        }

        afterEvaluate {
            project.tasks.each { task ->
                if (task.name.startsWith('collect') && task.name.endsWith('MultiDexComponents')) {
                    println "main-dex-filter: found task $task.name"
                    task.filter { name, attrs ->
                        def componentName = attrs.get('android:name')
                        if ('activity'.equals(name)) {
                            println "main-dex-filter: skipping, detected activity [$componentName]"
                            return false
                        } else {
                            println "main-dex-filter: keeping, detected $name [$componentName]"
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        productFlavors {
            // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
            dev {
                // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
                // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
                // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
                minSdkVersion 14
            }
            prod {
                // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
                minSdkVersion 14
            }
        }

        freeline {
            hack true
            productFlavor 'dev'
            applicationProxy false
        }

        signingConfigs {

            release {
                ....
            }
            debug{
                storeFile file("E:\\debug.keystore")

            }

        }

        buildTypes {

            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                minifyEnabled true
                //shrinkResources true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
            debug {
                testCoverageEnabled = true
            }
        }

        dexOptions {
            preDexLibraries = false
            javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
            incremental true 
        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
            disable "ignore", "IgnoreResLayout", "InvalidPackage", "MissingRegistered"
        }

        //useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }



    dependencies {
        compile project(':jni')
        compile(name:'ormlite', ext:'aar')
        compile(name:'customswipelistview', ext:'aar')
        compile(name:'pullrefresh', ext:'aar')
        compile(name:'viewpagerindicator', ext:'aar')
        compile(name:'weibosdk', ext:'aar')
        compile(name:'android_gif_drawable', ext:'aar')
        compile project(':common')
        compile(name:'pdfium',ext:'aar')
        compile ('in.srain.cube:ultra-ptr:1.0.11'){
            exclude module: 'support-v4'
        }
        compile ('com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'){
            exclude module: 'support-v4'
        }


        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:21.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
        compile 'in.srain.cube:ultra-ptr:1.0.11'
        compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
        compile files('libs/AMap_Services_V2.3.1.jar')
        compile files('libs/AMap_Location_V3.3.0_20170118.jar')
        compile files('libs/Android_Map3D_SDK_V4.1.2_20161104.jar')
        compile files('libs/mta-sdk-1.0.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/open_sdk.jar')
        compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
        compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.8.jar')
        compile(name:'qiniusdk7.3', ext:'aar')
        compile files('libs/zxing.jar')
        compile files('libs/OpenApi_v1.5_20140811.jar')
        compile files('libs/pushservice-5.6.0.30.jar')
        compile files('libs/MiPush_SDK_Client_3_2_2.jar')
        compile files('libs/HwPush_SDK_V2559.jar')
        compile files('libs/alipaySdk-20151112.jar')
        compile files('libs/conceal_android.jar')
        compile files('libs/libconceal.jar')
        compile files('libs/eventbus-3.0.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/TencentLocationSDK_v5.0.1_r251203_170116_1729.jar')
        compile 'com.meizu.flyme.internet:push-internal-publish:3.3.170329@aar'
        compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
        compile 'com.qiniu:happy-dns:0.2.7'

        compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.9'

        debugCompile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'
        debugCompile ('com.wanjian:sak:0.1.0') {
            exclude (group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7')
        }

        // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        //androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
        // JUnit4 Rules
       // androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
        // Optional -- Mockito framework
        //androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.1.0'
        androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.6.3'

        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        }
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
        }
    }

    /*def patchKeepSpecs() {
        def taskClass = "com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.multidex.CreateManifestKeepList";
        def clazz = this.class.classLoader.loadClass(taskClass)
        def keepSpecsField = clazz.getDeclaredField("KEEP_SPECS")
        keepSpecsField.setAccessible(true)
        def keepSpecsMap = (Map) keepSpecsField.get(null)
        if (keepSpecsMap.remove("activity") != null) {
            println "KEEP_SPECS patched: removed 'activity' root"
        } else {
            println "Failed to patch KEEP_SPECS: no 'activity' root found"
        }
    }

    patchKeepSpecs()*/
```

and the gradle log as follows:

```
    Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDevDebug]

    Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
    freeline auto add runtime dependencies: 0.8.3
    WARNING: The `android.dexOptions.incremental` property is deprecated and it has no effect on the build process.
    Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
    variant prodDebug is not dev, skip hack process.
    variant prodRelease is not debug, skip hack process.
    find variant devDebug start hack process...
    variant devRelease is not debug, skip hack process.
    :app:preBuild
    :common:preBuild
    :jni:preBuild
    :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preBuild spend 13ms
    :common:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :common:preBuild spend 16ms
    :jni:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:preBuild spend 17ms
    :app:preDevDebugBuild
    :common:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :common:preReleaseBuild spend 2ms
    :app:preDevDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preDevDebugBuild spend 2ms
    :jni:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:preReleaseBuild spend 1ms
    :jni:checkReleaseManifest
    :common:checkReleaseManifest
    :app:checkDevDebugManifest
    :app:checkDevDebugManifest spend 0ms
    :jni:checkReleaseManifest spend 0ms
    :app:extractProguardFiles
    :common:checkReleaseManifest spend 0ms
    :app:extractProguardFiles spend 0ms
    :jni:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:preDebugAndroidTestBuild spend 0ms
    :jni:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:preDebugBuild spend 0ms
    :jni:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:preDebugUnitTestBuild spend 1ms
    :jni:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:preReleaseUnitTestBuild spend 0ms
    :jni:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72102Library
    :common:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :common:preDebugAndroidTestBuild spend 0ms
    :common:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :common:preDebugBuild spend 0ms
    :common:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :common:preDebugUnitTestBuild spend 1ms
    :common:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :common:preReleaseUnitTestBuild spend 0ms
    :app:preDevReleaseBuild
    :app:preDevReleaseBuild spend 0ms
    :app:preProdDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preProdDebugBuild spend 0ms
    :app:preProdReleaseBuild
    :app:preProdReleaseBuild spend 0ms
    :app:preDevDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preDevDebugAndroidTestBuild spend 0ms
    :app:preProdDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preProdDebugAndroidTestBuild spend 0ms
    :app:generateDevDebugBuildConfig
    :jni:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72102Library UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72102Library spend 49ms
    :common:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72102Library
    :jni:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42102Library UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42102Library spend 18ms
    :app:generateDevDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDevDebugBuildConfig spend 18ms
    :app:generateDevDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDevDebugResValues spend 1ms
    :app:incrementalDevDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
    :jni:prepareReleaseDependencies
    :jni:prepareReleaseDependencies spend 2ms
    :jni:compileReleaseAidl
    :common:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72102Library UP-TO-DATE
    :common:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72102Library spend 26ms
    :common:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42102Library
    :jni:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:compileReleaseAidl spend 3ms
    :jni:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:compileReleaseNdk spend 1ms
    :jni:compileLint UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:compileLint spend 3ms
    :jni:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:copyReleaseLint spend 1ms
    :common:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42102Library UP-TO-DATE
    :common:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42102Library spend 2ms
    :jni:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:compileReleaseRenderscript spend 3ms
    :common:prepareReleaseDependencies
    :common:prepareReleaseDependencies spend 0ms
    :jni:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:generateReleaseBuildConfig spend 2ms
    :common:compileReleaseAidl
    :jni:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:generateReleaseResValues spend 1ms
    :jni:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:generateReleaseResources spend 1ms
    :jni:mergeReleaseResources
    :common:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :common:compileReleaseAidl spend 12ms
    :common:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
    :common:compileReleaseNdk spend 1ms
    :common:compileLint UP-TO-DATE
    :common:compileLint spend 1ms
    :common:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
    :common:copyReleaseLint spend 0ms
    :common:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :common:compileReleaseRenderscript spend 3ms
    :common:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :common:generateReleaseBuildConfig spend 2ms
    :common:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :common:generateReleaseResValues spend 1ms
    :common:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :common:generateReleaseResources spend 0ms
    :common:mergeReleaseResources
    :jni:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:mergeReleaseResources spend 48ms
    :jni:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:processReleaseManifest spend 4ms
    :jni:processReleaseResources
    :common:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :common:mergeReleaseResources spend 72ms
    :common:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :common:processReleaseManifest spend 2ms
    :common:processReleaseResources
    :jni:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:processReleaseResources spend 46ms
    :jni:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:generateReleaseSources spend 0ms
    :jni:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
    :common:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :common:processReleaseResources spend 4ms
    :common:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
    :common:generateReleaseSources spend 0ms
    :common:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
    :jni:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard spend 2ms
    :jni:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
    :common:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
    :common:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard spend 4ms
    :common:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
    :common:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac spend 27ms
    :common:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
    :common:extractReleaseAnnotations spend 21ms
    :common:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
    :common:mergeReleaseShaders spend 1ms
    :common:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
    :common:compileReleaseShaders spend 9ms
    :common:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :common:generateReleaseAssets spend 0ms
    :common:mergeReleaseAssets
    :jni:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac spend 83ms
    :jni:extractReleaseAnnotations
    :common:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :common:mergeReleaseAssets spend 25ms
    :common:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
    :common:mergeReleaseProguardFiles spend 3ms
    :common:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :common:packageReleaseRenderscript spend 0ms
    :common:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :common:packageReleaseResources spend 5ms
    :common:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
    :common:processReleaseJavaRes spend 1ms
    :common:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :common:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease spend 108ms
    :common:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
    :jni:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:extractReleaseAnnotations spend 6ms
    :jni:mergeReleaseShaders
    :common:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :common:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease spend 1ms
    :jni:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:mergeReleaseShaders spend 1ms
    :jni:compileReleaseShaders
    :common:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
    :jni:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:compileReleaseShaders spend 1ms
    :common:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
    :common:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders spend 1ms
    :common:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
    :jni:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:generateReleaseAssets spend 0ms
    :jni:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:mergeReleaseAssets spend 1ms
    :jni:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:mergeReleaseProguardFiles spend 0ms
    :jni:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:packageReleaseRenderscript spend 0ms
    :common:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :common:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease spend 0ms
    :jni:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:packageReleaseResources spend 5ms
    :jni:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:processReleaseJavaRes spend 0ms
    :jni:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease spend 2ms
    :jni:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
    :common:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :common:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease spend 2ms
    :common:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :common:bundleRelease spend 3ms
    :jni:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease spend 16ms
    :jni:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders spend 2ms
    :jni:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease spend 2ms
    :jni:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease spend 3ms
    :jni:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :jni:bundleRelease spend 2ms
    :app:incrementalDevDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard spend 6171ms
    :app:prepareAndroid_gif_drawableLibrary UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareAndroid_gif_drawableLibrary spend 2ms
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72102Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72102Library spend 10ms
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72301Library spend 3ms
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportGridlayoutV72102Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportGridlayoutV72102Library spend 2ms
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library spend 1ms
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library spend 1ms
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library spend 3ms
    :app:prepareComAntfortuneFreelineRuntime083Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAntfortuneFreelineRuntime083Library spend 2ms
    :app:prepareComMeizuFlymeInternetPushInternalPublish33170329Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComMeizuFlymeInternetPushInternalPublish33170329Library spend 3ms
    :app:prepareComWanjianSak010Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComWanjianSak010Library spend 2ms
    :app:prepareCustomswipelistviewLibrary UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareCustomswipelistviewLibrary spend 1ms
    :app:prepareInSrainCubeUltraPtr1011Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareInSrainCubeUltraPtr1011Library spend 2ms
    :app:prepareOrmliteLibrary UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareOrmliteLibrary spend 3ms
    :app:preparePdfiumLibrary UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preparePdfiumLibrary spend 2ms
    :app:preparePocket_proCommonUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preparePocket_proCommonUnspecifiedLibrary spend 2ms
    :app:preparePocket_proJniUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preparePocket_proJniUnspecifiedLibrary spend 2ms
    :app:preparePullrefreshLibrary UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preparePullrefreshLibrary spend 2ms
    :app:prepareQiniusdk73Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareQiniusdk73Library spend 2ms
    :app:prepareViewpagerindicatorLibrary UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareViewpagerindicatorLibrary spend 3ms
    :app:prepareWeibosdkLibrary UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareWeibosdkLibrary spend 3ms
    :app:prepareDevDebugDependencies
    :app:prepareDevDebugDependencies spend 0ms
    :app:compileDevDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDevDebugAidl spend 10ms
    :app:compileDevDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDevDebugRenderscript spend 4ms
    :app:generateDevDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDevDebugResources spend 1ms
    :app:mergeDevDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeDevDebugResources spend 483ms
    :app:processDevDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processDevDebugManifest spend 8ms
    :app:processDevDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processDevDebugResources spend 49ms
    :app:generateDevDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDevDebugSources spend 1ms
    :app:compileDevDebugJavaWithJavac
    :app:compileDevDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
    :app:compileDevDebugJavaWithJavac spend 51746ms
    :app:compileDevDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDevDebugNdk spend 1ms
    :app:compileDevDebugSources
    :app:compileDevDebugSources spend 0ms
    :app:mergeDevDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeDevDebugShaders spend 2ms
    :app:compileDevDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDevDebugShaders spend 2ms
    :app:generateDevDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDevDebugAssets spend 1ms
    :app:mergeDevDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeDevDebugAssets spend 9ms
    :app:unzipJacocoAgent UP-TO-DATE
    :app:unzipJacocoAgent spend 19ms
    :app:transformClassesWithJacocoForDevDebug UP-TO-DATE
    :app:transformClassesWithJacocoForDevDebug spend 551ms
    :app:transformClassesWithAspectTransformForDevDebug UP-TO-DATE
    :app:transformClassesWithAspectTransformForDevDebug spend 821ms
    :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDevDebug UP-TO-DATE
    :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDevDebug spend 2ms
    :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDevDebug UP-TO-DATE
    :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDevDebug spend 2ms
    :app:transformClassesWithDexForDevDebug
```

More with "--info":

```
...
:jni:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:jni:packageReleaseResources spend 3ms
:jni:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:jni:processReleaseJavaRes spend 0ms
:jni:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:jni:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease spend 1ms
:jni:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:jni:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease spend 14ms
:jni:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:jni:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders spend 1ms
:jni:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:jni:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease spend 2ms
:jni:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:jni:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease spend 2ms
:jni:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:jni:bundleRelease spend 1ms
:app:prepareAndroid_gif_drawableLibrary UP-TO-DATE
Reading library jar [D:\Users\sf\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\lib\shrinkedAndroid.jar]
Preparing output jar [D:\pocket_pro\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\dev\debug\componentClasses.jar]
  Copying resources from program jar [D:\pocket_pro\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\dev\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar]
Executing java process:                                          
Starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java.exe''. Working directory: D:\pocket_pro\app Command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java.exe -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser
.country=CN -Duser.language=zh -Duser.variant -cp D:\Users\sf\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\lib\dx.jar com.android.multidex.ClassReferenceListBuilder D:\pocket_pro\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\dev\debug\
componentClasses.jar D:\pocket_pro\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\dev\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar
Successfully started process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java.exe''
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDevDebug spend 11974ms   
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDevDebug (Thread[Task worker,5,main]) completed. Took 11.975 secs.
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDevDebug (Thread[Task worker Thread 2,5,main]) started.
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDevDebug
Executing task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDevDebug' (up-to-date check took 0.002 secs) due to:
  Input file D:\pocket_pro\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\dev\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar has changed.
  Input file D:\pocket_pro\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\dev\debug\maindexlist.txt has changed.
Transform inputs calculations based on following changes
D:\pocket_pro\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\dev\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar:CHANGED
D:\pocket_pro\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\dev\debug\maindexlist.txt:CHANGED
Task is incremental : false
JarInputs ImmutableJarInput{name=combined, file=D:\pocket_pro\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\dev\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=PROJECT,PROJECT_LOCAL_DEPS,SUB_PROJECTS,SUB_PROJECTS
_LOCAL_DEPS,EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=NOTCHANGED}
DirInputs
Dexing in-process : D:\pocket_pro\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\dev\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar
> Building 94% > :app:transformClassesWithDexForDevDebug
```

And more with "-- debug"

```
    ...
    11:28:44.362 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Determining if task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDevDebug' is up-to-date
    11:28:44.365 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Executing task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDevDebug' (up-to-date check took 0.003 secs) due to:
      Output file D:\pocket_pro\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\dev\debug\folders\1000\1f\main\classes2.dex has been removed.
      Output file D:\pocket_pro\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\dev\debug\folders\1000\1f\main\classes.dex has been removed.
      Output file D:\pocket_pro\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\dev\debug\folders\1000\1f\main\classes3.dex has been removed.
    11:28:44.365 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter] Executing actions for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDevDebug'.
    11:28:44.368 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.RebuildIncrementalTaskInputs] All input files are considered out-of-date for incremental task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDevDebug'.
    11:28:44.372 [INFO] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApplicationTaskManager] Task is incremental : false
    11:28:44.373 [INFO] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApplicationTaskManager] JarInputs ImmutableJarInput{name=combined, file=D:\pocket_pro\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\dev\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar, co
    ntentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=PROJECT,PROJECT_LOCAL_DEPS,SUB_PROJECTS,SUB_PROJECTS_LOCAL_DEPS,EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=NOTCHANGED}
    11:28:44.373 [INFO] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApplicationTaskManager] DirInputs
    11:28:44.384 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Allocated dexExecutorService of size 4.
    11:28:44.386 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Dexing in-process : D:\pocket_pro\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\dev\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar
    11:29:33.555 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
    11:29:33.556 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonStatus] GC rate: 0.0/s
    11:29:33.557 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
    11:29:33.557 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
    11:29:33.561 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
    11:30:33.555 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
    11:30:33.555 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonStatus] GC rate: 0.0/s
    11:30:33.555 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
    11:30:33.555 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
    11:30:33.556 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
    11:30:34.535 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonStatus] GC rate: 0.0/s
    11:30:34.545 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
    11:30:34.555 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:30:34.556 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
    > Building 94% > :app:transformClassesWithDexForDevDebug
```

the last 4 lines is looped.

Comment: Could you run gradle with "--info", this will give us more details of your problem. If "--info" isn't showing anything helpful, then maybe even it with "--debug". Please then post the info or debug log also here.

Comment: Here are more messages....   It seems jammed at " Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry."

Comment: It seems like the reason replied by Ashik Vetrivelu in [Gradle Build too long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849945/gradle-build-too-long), but I need keep "testCoverageEnabled" = true to get reports, so I take out productFlavors in app.gradle,  but it is still stunk.