# Android Unit tests running forever in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, junit, android-gradle-plugin, android-instrumentation

For whatever reason the unit tests in Android Studio will not stop running despite hitting the stop button multiple times.

I've tried `./gradlew --stop` in the terminal already, and I've also checked [Android Instrumentation Tests Stuck "Running Tests" Forever Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839495/android-instrumentation-tests-stuck-running-tests-forever-android-studio), as well as well as [Gradle Build too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849945/gradle-build-too-long/39865956#39865956), but they did not solve my problem.

If someone can please help me I will greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

[Picture of android Studio screen showing the running processes in the top right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrgiT.png)

Comment: but the image shows that process exited with code 0, and 1 test passed.. !

Comment: So, to be clear, that does mean that no tests are being executed? How come it still shows that there are processes running?